# How to connect a car camera to a mobile application

Tags: android, camera

I want to develop mobie app. It will analyse the image sent from the car cameras. **I'm looking for idea how to connect this camera to my app.** I would like to use wifi or bluetooth to send an image.

I found a few **cheap** cameras like these(GO PRO is a bit too expensive for this project):

- https://orllo.pl/kamera-samochodowa-4k.html
- https://www.blackvue.com/dr900s-2ch-ir/

but it doesn't have to be specifically those models.

--

UPDATE:

I'm looking for SDK of cameras or code example how to obtain the images.

Comment: Maybe you can look at this one -> https://docs.mapbox.com/android/vision/overview/

Answer (score 1):

Consider use a micro-controller, such as raspberry pi, with a camera module ($5-$20).

Answer (score 0):

You can control a GoPro Hero camera from an app on your phone.  The way they do it is that the camera generates its own WiFi hotspot, and you switch your phone's WiFi setting to the camera's WiFi hotspot.  Then, you can communicate with the camera over WiFi.  However, while you are doing that, your phone may not be able to reach the internet while connected to the camera because it is on a closed WiFi network (maybe it can still connect over LTE)

Comment: I don't want to use dedicated app for camera. I need pictures in my app. I analyse them. Can I connect GoPro with some other application? Is there any dedicated API.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you use their dedicated app.  I was using that as an example of what and how you could do the same.

Comment: I have added more details to the question